# chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate event is not executed immediately after window.location change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webpack, babeljs

Note that I'm using `Babel` + `Webpack` to generate `ES2017` code to `ES5` (I'm using `async` `await` functionalities and wiling to use same code with less changes in old browsers).

My goal is here to execute # of codes on a specific tab. Those codes includes, form submits, clicking on links etc.. which redirects to a new webpage. What ever the code should be paused until the page is loaded doesn't matter what is the page it's navigating/redirecting. So to simulate the redirecting I'm using `window.location = "https://facebook.com"`.

Every thing in short. The expected behavior is,

1. I open tab with `url: 'https://google.com'`
2. Change the window location to `https://facebook.com`
3. Display alert message once `facebook` loaded completely.

I have below helper classes with me.

## tabs.js

```
/** Tabs class will provide promisify chrome.tabs functions */
export default class Tabs {

    /** Creates a new tab using passed configurations
     * @param {Object} config
     *  {Number} windowId
     *  {Number} index
     *  {String} url
     *  {Boolean} active
     *  {Boolean} pinned
     *  {Number} openerTabId ID of the tab that opened current tab. should be in the same window.
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    static create(config) {

        // Return new promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // Creating new tab
            chrome.tabs.create(config, (tab) => {

                // Error
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    reject(chrome.extension.lastError);

                // Success
                else
                    resolve(tab);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param {Number} id
     * @param {Object} config
     *  {String} code // javascript or css code to inject
     *  {String} file // javascript or css file to inject
     *  {Boolean} allFrames // inject to all frames
     *  {Number} frameId // frame index to inject
     *  {Boolean} matchAboutBlank // inject tp about:blank pages
     *  {String} runAt // "document_start" or "document_end" or "document_idle"
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    static execute(id, config) {

        // Return a new promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // Execute a script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, config, (results) => {

                // Error
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    reject(chrome.runtime.las2tError);

                // Success
                else{
                    resolve(results);
                    // print "execute" just to get the idea when it's printed.
                    console.log('executed: ' + config.code);
                }
            });
        })
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param {Number} id
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    static get(id) {

        // Return new promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // Get tab
            chrome.tabs.get(id, (tab) => {

                // Error
                if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);

                // Success
                else
                    resolve(tab);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

## process.js

```
export default class Process {

    /** Pause for a given time
     * @param ms
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    static timeout(ms) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, ms);
        });
    }
}
```

Finally my `background.js` is used to listen to `webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` and `webNavigation.onCompleted` and to execute script.

Note that `onBeforeNavigate` and `onCompleted` provide details about each and every tab but when i run this i only have one tab. so I'm directly initializing `isTabStatus` without `tabId` validation.

## background.js

```
import Tabs from "./tab/tabs";
import Process from "./commons/process";

// holds the status of new tab.
let isTabStatus = "loading";

/**
 * Listeners
 */
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener((info) => {
    if(info.frameId === 0) {
        console.log('before navigation status: loading ' + info.url);
        isTabStatus = "loading";
    }
});

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((info) => {
    if(info.frameId === 0) {
        console.log('on completed status: completed ' + info.url);
        isTabStatus = "completed";
    }
});




async function run() {
    let tab = await Tabs.create({
        url: "https://www.google.com"
    });

    let tabId = tab.id;

    await waitUntilLoaded();

    await Tabs.execute(tabId, {
        code: "window.location = 'https://facebook.com'",
        runAt: "document_idle"
    });

    await waitUntilLoaded();

    await Tabs.execute(tabId, {
        code: "alert('hello world')"
    });
}

async function waitUntilLoaded () {
    while(isTabStatus === "loading") {
        await Process.timeout(400);
        console.log('waiting');
    }
}

run();
```

So, the expected behavior is,

1. create new tab
2. navigate to `https://google.com`
3. navigate to `https://facebook.com`
4. alert `hello world`.

But it actually does is,

1. create new tab
2. navigate to `https://google.com`
3. alert `hello world`
4. navigate to `https://facebook.com`

Finally the console logs as below.

```
before navigation status: loading https://www.google.com/
waiting
on completed status: completed https://www.google.lk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VIueWa2uFZOCuATNtJTIBA
waiting
execute: window.location = 'https://facebook.com'
before navigation status: loading https://facebook.com/
execute: alert('hello world')
on completed status: completed https://www.facebook.com/
```

In here `alert` has completed executed after `onBeforeNavigate` but actually `alert` message is displayed in the `google` page. After and only after I click ok (alert message ok), It redirects to `facebook`.

It's clear if i add `console.log` before `alert` as below.

```
await waitUntilLoaded();

console.log('****');
await Tabs.execute(tabId, {
    code: "alert('hello world')"
});
```

Then the final log will be,

```
before navigation status: loading https://www.google.com/
waiting
on completed status: completed https://www.google.lk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TY-eWb_0D6baugTMqqWACQ
waiting
execute: window.location = 'https://facebook.com'
****
before navigation status: loading https://facebook.com/
execute: alert('hello world')
on completed status: completed https://www.facebook.com/
```

As you can see alert get executed immediately after `window.location` change. even before `onBeforeNavigation` callback

Find other details below.

## mainfest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Tax Executer",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "views/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "file:///*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": "views/background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": ["https://*/*", "file://*/*"],
      "js": ["dist/content.js"]
    }],

  "automation": {}
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "babel_webpack_starter_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "helps you to get started with babel + webpack project quickly",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "babel": "babel"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SrineshNisala/babel_webpack_starter_project.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "babel",
    "webpack",
    "starter"
  ],
  "author": "SrineshNisala",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/SrineshNisala/babel_webpack_starter_project/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SrineshNisala/babel_webpack_starter_project#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-unassert": "^2.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "enumify": "^1.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        background: "./src/background.js",
        content: "./src/content.js",
        popup: "./src/popup.js"
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "stage-1"],
                plugins: [
                    "transform-runtime",
                    // "babel-plugin-unassert"
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

## Instruction to run

To run, place all the files in a folder use `npm install` to install all the dependencies. and use `npm run webpack` to compile the code to dist folder. use the dist folder `background.js` as the `background script`.

## I tried

Same process without `babel` or `webpack`, even without any `promises`. Find the `background.js` below

## background.js

```
var isCompleted = false;

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener((info) => {
    if(info.frameId === 0) {
        console.log('before navigation ' + info.url);
        isCompleted = false;
    }
});

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((info) => {
    if(info.frameId === 0) {
        console.log('on completed ' + info.url);
        isCompleted = true;
    }
});

// Create tab
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "https://google.com"
}, (tab) => {

    console.log("tab created");

    // Navigate to facebook.com
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com'",
        runAt: "document_idle"
    }, () => {

        console.log("window location changed, current tabs is completed: " + isCompleted);

        // Wait until facebook is loaded
        if(!isCompleted) {
            console.log('waiting until facebook is loaded');

            setTimeout(() => {

                // Alert hello world
                chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                    code: "alert('hello world')",
                    runAt: "document_idle"
                }, () => {
                    console.log("alert executed");
                });
            }, 5000);

        } else {
            console.log("**** tab status has not been changed even if it's navigating to facebook.com ****");
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                code: "alert('hello world')",
                runAt: "document_idle"
            }, () => {
                console.log("alert executed");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Result I get still the same as before. `console.log as below`

```
tab created
before navigation https://google.com/
on completed https://www.google.lk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=CVCfWervItzLugSemrqAAw
window location changed, current tabs is completed: true
**** tab status has not been changed even if it's navigating to facebook.com ****
before navigation https://www.facebook.com/
alert executed
on completed https://www.facebook.com/
```

## I tried

Once we executed `window.location`, i guess there is a little time gap between current page unloading and new page is loading. So I listened to `window.onBeforeUnload` event in `content script` and passed a message to runtime once it's occurred.

## content.js

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "onbeforeunload"});
});
```

I listened to the message from `background script`.

## background.js

```
var isCompleted = false;


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.type === "onbeforeunload") {
            console.log("page is unloading");
            isCompleted = false;
        }
    }
);
```

But ended up getting this message even after `webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` callback.

Comment: *Please* try your extension without having processed the code with babel. You don't have to eventually release it that way, but doing so will separate any issues that arise specifically because of your use of babel. It will also make it more likely for other people to take a look at your code. A very significant percentage of questions on SO about Google Chrome extensions are a result of someone trying to use a package/library/tool that is intended for use in webpages that *just doesn't work* as expected in a Chrome extension. Please remove this possibility by testing w/o using babel.

Comment: If you insist on using babel for testing/development, then please post the generated code *instead of* the code you are using to source to babel. Alternately, *at a bare minimum* provide all configuration settings you use, what you've installed, etc. for babel and describe *exactly* how you are changing the files. The point of a [mcve] is that we can duplicate your problem. We need to be able to test the code that you are *actually using*. The use of babel makes that problematic based on what we have in the question. As this is, it's still a black box (way too many ways babel could be used).

Comment: In general, it is against policy to delete your [oh-hold question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45850020/3773011) to post a new version. While you did make substantial improvements in your question from the [version which was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45850020/1), the correct way to handle the situation is to try to get the question reopened. Your updated version *was* in the reopen queue, which allows users to review it for being reopened. The first edit after being put on-hold automatically puts it in that queue. However, doing so does take time.

Comment: One thing that you might have done is ping the people who had commented on your question to inform them of the updates you had done. I see that you did leave a comment, but nobody would have been notified about that comment. Note that I was informed about your earlier comment which pinged me using `@Makyen`, but not the one saying you had updated the question. More information on notifying users in comments:

Comment: So lazy to read those 1000 lines nonsense.

Comment: Ultimately, we're here because *we want to help*. You've made choices in what you are developing which make it significantly more complex and thus more difficult (requiring more time) to go through and determine both what you are trying to, what the code *should be doing as written* and what needs to be changed to make it work the way you want. That extra complexity/difficulty/additional time *significantly* reduces the number of people both able and *willing* to take that time to help you. I'm attempting to suggest ways to make it more likely that you actually get the help you're asking for.

Comment: FYI: You appear to be wrapping Chrome `chrome.*` APIs in Promises (e.g. `chrome.tabs`). As you may be aware, Firefox implements Promise based versions of many of these APIs using the `browser.*` namespace (Firefox also implements them as the callback versions in the `chrome.*` namespace). For use in Chrome, Mozilla [provides a polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) which implements Promise based wrappers for `chrome.*` APIs into the `browser.*` namespace. Using this library/polyfill may be less work for you than implementing your own wrappers.

Comment: Maybe someone will invest their time to answer this question, but I'll only state the obvious: it's either a bug in the browser or something wrong in your code, in which case breakpoints and stepping through code in devtools debugger should help as it usually does. If this is a bug you can report it on https://crbug.com but I'm afraid it'll be handled only if you can simplify the code to demonstrate the problem. If it's not a bug, I would try a workaround e.g. changing the url via tabs.update in the background page, and I wouldn't use onBeforeNavigate since there seems to be no real need.

Comment: I have change the question . i included a non babel non promise version. and i tried the code running. the result was the same.
As i have mentioned in the questions, 
_My goal is here to execute # of codes on a specific tab. Those codes includes, form submits, clicking on links etc.. which redirects to a new webpage. So to simulate the redirecting I'm using window.location = "https://facebook.com"._ 
`tabs.update` is not a solution.